# How to hide the highlighted lines when the ".sql" file are opened in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Below is what it looks like when opened the ".sql" file, I want to hide those highlighted lines

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found out that it comes with the SQL Tools extension
[image]

You could either uninstall it or revert back to 0.21.9 version. Not sure where the root cause for highlighting is.

Comment: Just got an email from the creator explaining that the highlighting is intentional (as expected)  to tell the user what is the current query part that will run (Run Current Query) and he will add a flag to turn ON/OFF.
Now that I understand the purpose it makes sense and is useful

Answer (score 21):

I'm the creator of VSCode-sqltools. In fact as @joao-caxias mentioned, that was intentional. But some users didn't like it at all, so I've added a setting to enable/disable that behavior called `sqltools.highlightQuery` so you should be able to remove that if you want now.

Comment: Thanks, Matheus. Can you please add support for Snowflake DB which is very much required and it hot piece in the market

Comment: Matheus Do you have any future plans to have Snowflake connection in VSCode

Answer (score 7):

You can go to SQLTools and click on the setting button. Then search highlight and uncheck the button for this setting.

[image: Link to image]